# «С 5-го по 13-й этажи займут отделения с палатами». Верно употребление в множ. числе - этажи?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

«С 5-го по 13-й этажи займут отделения с палатами». Верно употребление в множ. числе - этажи?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, построение неудачное. Варианты исправления (в порядке убывания моих предпочтений):

**Отделения с палатами займут этажи с 5-го по 13-й.**

**Этажи с 5-го по 13-й будут отведены отделениям с палатами.**

**Этажи с 5-го по 13-й будут заняты отделениями с палатами.**

**Этажи с 5-го по 13-й займут отделения с палатами.** (Читателю придется напрячься, чтобы понять, что займет что).

Сравните, здесь уместно говорить "с такого-то по такой-то этаж":

> Она даже не заметила мою экспозицию «Сотворение Мира», которая (как мне казалось) украшала Тайную Лестницу **с пятого по третий этаж**. [Марина Палей. Дань саламандре (2008)]
>
> Их дети, внуки и правнуки разукрасили все стены ― **с первого по пятый этаж** ― рисунками и надписями. [Юрий Буйда. Город палачей // «Знамя», 2003]

Comment: Или: Отделения с палатами займут  с 5-го по 13-й этаж. В таких случаях сущ. согласуется с последним прилагательным или порядковым числительным.

Comment: @Людмила. Сравните (какие, по-Вашему, за и против): "Отделения с палатами займут этажи с 5-го по 13-й" и "Отделения с палатами займут с 5-го по 13-й этаж"

Comment: По-моему, оба варианта подходят, на выбор автора.